# How to sums the squares of only the even numbers in a list of integers in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
evennum(N) :- 0 is N mod 2.
nonevennum(N) :- 1 is N mod 2.
sumsq_even([], 0).
sumsq_even([N | TailN], Sum) :-
  evennum(N), sumsq_even(TailN, S), Sum is S + N * N.
sumsq_even([N | TailN], Sum) :-
  sumsq_evennum(TailN, Sum),sumsq_even(TailN, S),Sum is S.
```

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: Where is `sumsq_evennum/2` defined?

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions and I've figured it out!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!